# VaadinCDIServlet Cookies.get(request, Constans)

Tags: java, vaadin

I found that code on vaadin forum
and I don't know how he get method **Cookies.get( request, Constants.VAADIN_THEME_COOKIE_NAME )**
Could anyone explain me that ?

```
public class CustomVaadinCDIServlet extends VaadinCDIServlet {

    @Override
    protected VaadinServletService createServletService( DeploymentConfiguration deploymentConfiguration ) throws ServiceException {
        final VaadinCDIServletService service = new VaadinCDIServletService(this, deploymentConfiguration) {
            @Override
            public String getConfiguredTheme( VaadinRequest request ) {
                final String theme = Cookies.get( request, Constants.VAADIN_THEME_COOKIE_NAME );
                return theme != null && Themes.contains( theme ) ? theme : Themes.VALO_facebook;
            }
        };
        service.init();
        return service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of thoughts for you, VaadinRequest extends HttpRequest, so you can do also

Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

(its javax.servlet.http.Cookie )

And then iterate cookies.

But if you just want to know the theme in use, there is method in UI for that, i.e. UI.getTheme()

And you can get UI e.g. with ui = request.getService().findUI(request) in your case.